# CSS Align Skill issue

Tags: html, css

I was trying to align the text in the center but when i try'd to do it and it worked, the license area goes off screen.

I try'd doing `margin-right: -1820px;` to align the original text, but when i did that the license text flew to the left. And im asking if there's a way to align both texts in the center.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85dG6.jpg)

```css
body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: #4a148c;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #222, #4a148c);
    color: #fff;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.countdown-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: -1820px;
}

h1 {
    color: #ff4081;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    right: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

#countdown {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 20px 0;
    color: #ff4081;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#message {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #e57373;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#license-area {
    --link-color: #007bff;
    --visited-link-color: #007bff;
    --hover-link-color: #0056b3;
    color: #f6f6f6;
    font-family: "korolev-condensed", sans-serif;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    grid-area: license;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 50px;
    line-height: 1;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

#license-area p {
    color: #f6f6f6;
}

#license-area a {
    color: #007bff;
}

#license-area a:hover {
    color: #0056b3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="countdown-container">
    <h1>???</h1>
    <h2>⚡ Working On It  </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="license-area" class="license-area">
    <p xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"><a property="dct:title" rel="cc:attributionURL" href="">Project "WebContainment"</a> by <span property="cc:attributionName">Maciupek</span> is licensed under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/?ref=chooser-v1" target="_blank" rel="license noopener noreferrer">CC BY-NC-SA 4.0</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to align the text to the center with `margin-right: -1820px;` But now the license text is off to the left. And im asking how to fix this or is there any way to align everything in the center, so nothing breakes

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: It's difficult to understand what the *intended* layout is here.  Did you mean for the `.container` element to use `flex-direction: column`?  By default those two child elements of that container are in a *row*, so they'd always be next to each other.  You've simply added a bunch of margin/spacing/etc. within them.

Comment: That's not at all how you align things. Large hard-coded values are almost never the right approach.

Comment: Have you tried: `.countdown-container { text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; width: 300px; display: inline-block; position: absolute; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather redesign the layout removing the license div from the container div and set it in a footer tag; text-align: center, centers the content. This simplifies the design.
Also, optimize your stylesheet: Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) where you can; look for selectors with similar styles and group them;

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #4a148c;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #222, #4a148c);
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.countdown-container {
  gap: 2em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1,
#countdown,
#message {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #ff4081;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#countdown {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#message {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #e57373;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#license-area {
  --link-color: #007bff;
  --visited-link-color: #007bff;
  --hover-link-color: #0056b3;
  color: #f6f6f6;
  font-family: "korolev-condensed", sans-serif;

  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  text-align: center;
}

#license-area p {
  color: #f6f6f6;
}

#license-area a {
  color: #007bff;
}

#license-area a:hover {
  color: #0056b3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="countdown-container">
        <h1>???</h1>
        <h2>⚡ Working On It </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div id="license-area" class="license-area">
        <p
          xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
          xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
        >
          <a property="dct:title" rel="cc:attributionURL" href=""
            >Project "WebContainment"</a
          >
          by <span property="cc:attributionName">Maciupek</span> is licensed
          under
          <a
            href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/?ref=chooser-v1"
            target="_blank"
            rel="license noopener noreferrer"
            >CC BY-NC-SA 4.0</a
          >
        </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
```